# Is writing a single value into a uninitialised pointer in c++ acceptable?

Tags: c++

Is this considered safe ?

```
int *a;
*a = 5;
```

or should i always do

```
int *a = new int[1];
*a = 5;
```

Comment: Both of those are wrong.

Comment: Answering to the question in title: no, its should immediately crash.

Comment: @mvp writing to memory via an uninitialized pointer is **undefined behavior**, ANYTHING can happen, a crash is not guaranteed. You may instead simply corrupt memory and not crash at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such code is an undefined behavior: it may crash (e.g. if you try to write outside your program's space) or it may behave in very strange way (e.g. if it points to place where another variable is stored; it will take forever to find a bug).

The following is safe (as long as you use pointer only when `val` is still alive):

```
int val;
int *a = &val;
*a = 1;
```

This works, since `a` uses space reserved for `val` (and now `val` equals to `1`).

In your second example `new int[1]` should work, I think, since you need to reserve space for 1 integer.

Comment: i thought c++ used indexing from 0  for everything so to declare a memory space of 1 int I should have used new int[0] ; thanks for the clarification

Comment: @RichuShajiAbraham `new int[0]` is not valid. You can't allocate an array with 0 elements in it. But you don't need to allocate an array if all you want is 1 element, `new int` will suffice by itself. But using `new` to allocate a single `int` is way overkill in 99% of cases.